# Trigger the mouse event while moving | PoitnerLockControl | Mouse Event | React Three Fiber

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

In this example, I have 2 boxes. When I hover to a box, this will change the color to be pink.
The problem is when I hover a box and keep this mouse (don't move the mouse) and move the camera, the box still be pink until I move the camera outside of the box scope.

My question is: How to fix that? How can I trigger the mouse event when I'm moving?

My Demo: https://react-three-fiber-demo-chi.vercel.app/
My Code: https://github.com/hung-viet/react-three-fiber-demo

I've researched it for 2 weeks but still not find out any answers.